# MySQL results issue in php array

Tags: php, sql

Can anybody tell me why not all the results for MySQL aren't ending up in the array?

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from groups order by id desc");

if ($row = $result->fetch()) {
$groups[] = $row; 
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Just edited it to include the notice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have there does not iterate over the result set.
Try this instead.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch()) { 
$groups[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `while` not `if`

```
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
  $groups[] = $row; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because fetch only fetches a row as explained in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> Fetches the next row from a result set

I'd like to suggest changing your mysql_ code for PDO

```
$db = new PDO("..."); // Creates the PDO object. Put the right arguments for your connection.
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM groups ORDER BY id DESC");
$statement->execute();
while ($groups = $statement->fetch())
  {
  // Do whatever you want to do

  }
```